# Super Difficult addClass Delay function w/ diff timed intervals

Tags: jquery, timeout, addclass

Total Novice here. I have some list items. I need to add a class of '.go' to each list item, one at a time, spaced out by pre-determined blocks of time. (each block of time will be different durations).

**For instance:**

1. the script adds a '.go' class to the first (li)
2. the '.go' class holds on that (li) for exactly 4.5 seconds.
3. once the 4.5 seconds are up, the script removes the '.go' class from the current list item
4. the script moves to the next (li) and adds a '.go' class
5. the '.go' class holds on this (li) for 1.5 seconds.
6. once the 1.5 seconds are up, the script removes the '.go' class from the current list item
7. And then the cycle repeats, until it has cycled through all the list items

The script I have been working on does not function. It adds all the classes to the (li)'s instantly. And then they fadeout at different intervals. Rather I need the classes to BE ADDED at different intervals. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bM6uY/8/

```
                         <ul>
                            <li>hello</li>
                            <li>World!</li>
                            <li>Foo</li>
                            <li>Bar</li>
                         </ul>
```

---

```
         $(function() {
           $('ul li:nth-child(1)').addClass("go")
                   .delay(4500)
                   .queue(function() {
                       $(this).removeClass("go");
                       $(this).dequeue();
                   });


            $('ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass("go")
                   .delay(1500)
                   .queue(function() {
                       $(this).removeClass("go");
                       $(this).dequeue();
                   });    


             $('ul li:nth-child(3)').addClass("go")
                   .delay(500)
                   .queue(function() {
                       $(this).removeClass("go");
                       $(this).dequeue();
                   });      


             $('ul li:nth-child(4)').addClass("go")
                   .delay(5000)
                   .queue(function() {
                       $(this).removeClass("go");
                       $(this).dequeue();
                   });                              
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var index = 0;
    var length = $("ul").children().length;
    var delays = [
            500,
            1500,
            500,
            5000
    ];

    function delayNext()
    {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("ul li:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("go").siblings().removeClass("go");
            index++;

            if (index == length)
                index = 0;

            delayNext();
        }, delays[index]);
    }

    delayNext();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rfvgyhn/9VL4r/2/

Comment: thats really close but how would I add multiple/different delay values? Instead of them having all the same exact delay amount?

Comment: Cool, but how do I assign different delays for each cycle?

Comment: Sorry about that, I must have been a little hasty when I read your question. See edits.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much, this is perfect! I'm testing it now. (Really impressed w/ the community here)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the the 4 queues to something like the following:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(1)').delay(4500)
                       .queue(function() {
                           $('ul li').removeClass( "go" );
                           $(this).addClass("go");
                           $(this).dequeue();
                       });
```

Here's the whole thing: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMH/bM6uY/18/

Comment: @ChrisHogan - thx but doesnt work, it jus stick on the first li - http://jsfiddle.net/bM6uY/12/

Comment: @ChrisHogan Awesome! Almost there, how do I remove the classes before adding the next one to the next li item  http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMH/bM6uY/9/

Comment: Just remove all the instances of the go class.  Example updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMH/bM6uY/18/

Comment: @ChrisHogan is there any way to force the script to work in a linear fashion? Meaning, that it will NOT add any classes to any of the list items UNTIL the block of time is over. As it is working now, which ever (li) has the shortest time delay gets displayed first. I need the first (li) to display first for 4.5 seconds, then the second (li) for (x) seconds, then the 3rd (li) for (x) seconds?

Comment: Look like one of the other answers (Rfvgyhn) does exactly that.